# How do I disallow a specific query string in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt, query-string

I have the URL

```
http://www.example.com/shopping/books/?b=9
```

and the following `robots.txt` file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /?b=9
```

But when I test this in Google Webmaster Tool's robots.txt tester it is showing allowed when it should be disallowed.

Whilst `/?b=9` is fixed, `/shopping/books` will change with different categories and I need to block them all.

Please tell me what's wrong with my robots.txt.

Comment: Do you want to block only `/shopping/books/?b=9` or all `/shopping/books/` ? Do you have rewrite rules on this folder ? more info there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149782/ignore-urls-in-robot-txt-with-specific-parameters

Comment: Did you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149782/ignore-urls-in-robot-txt-with-specific-parameters

Comment: @Froggiz 
I want to Block only /shopping/books/?b=9 ,, /shopping/books/ is Importent URLs and Can't disallow them

Answer (score 6):

`robots.txt` is *prefix matching*, so a rule like `Disallow: /?b=9` will block all URLs that *start* `/?b=9`. Your URLs start `/shopp...` so they are not blocked.

However, you can use a `*` (wildcard - 0 or more instances of any character) to represent the first part of the URL. This is an addition to the "standard", but the main search engine bots (["Google, Bing, Yahoo, and Ask"](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt?hl=en#url-matching-based-on-path-values)) support it:

```
Disallow /*/?b=9
```

The above should block `/shopping/books/?b=9` and `/<anything>/?b=9`.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt?hl=en#url-matching-based-on-path-values

Comment: Which should be follow ? Because my directory is /shopping/books/?b=9 
      Disallow /*/?b=9
               Or 
      Disallow: /*/*/?b=9

Comment: the answer is in his post

Comment: It doesn't really matter, `*` matches _any_ character (including `/`). Unless you specifically need to check for 2 path segments then use the former (as stated in my answer).

Comment: Keep in mind that the wildcard (*) is supported by Google but not part of the robots.txt standard.  Most bots won't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on the link i posted :

```
Disallow: /shopping/*/*?b=9
```

`*` is a joker which mean "all"

Comment: We can't do that because  numbers of url have as /shopping/mobile/?=9   ,  /shopping/bags/?=9.......  So please give proper solution for this

Comment: I updated my answer, but you should have found it by yourself

Comment: May be wrong.... Didn't clear that

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's such a way to do it in robots.txt and also whatever is advertised in robots.txt is also what can be advertised to hackers because robots.txt is a file accessible to all.

What I would suggest is to use your scripting language to detect for the query string you don't want people to access and if the query string matches, create a redirect to a relevant page people are allowed to access or take them to a page with a 410 HTTP code.

For example, in PHP, you can use either of these to block the `b=9` parameter from being accessible:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['b']=="9"){
header("HTTP/1.1 410 Gone",true);
echo "This page is gone.";
exit();
}
?>

<?php
if ($_GET['b']=="9"){
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Redirect",true);
header("Location: http://example.com/newpage",true);
echo "This page moved <a href=\"http://example.com/newpage\">here</a>";
exit();
}
?>
```

If you are looking to specifically block just robots and not real users, then you could make the parameters accessible via POST only. Here's the HTML and PHP you can use:

Html:

```
<form action="phpscript.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="b" value="9">
<input type="submit" value="special page">
</form>
```

Php file named phpscript.php:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['b']=="9" && strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != "POST"){
header("HTTP/1.1 410 Gone",true);
echo "This page is gone";
exit();
}
?>
```

Only problem with the post method is that making post requests are generally non-cacheable based requests since they're primarily meant for user data submission.

Comment: I don;t want to go with 410. because need to stop crawling and indexing for this specific pages /?b=9

Comment: A 410 status sent to search engine bots means the page is "gone" and that they should stop scanning it. A 404 status means not found and that they can rescan it at a later point hoping it'd come back.